# Google Signin error when changing package name in React Native Android app

Tags: android, google-signin, react-native, package-name

I've set up a React Native Android app using the [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) package, and everything is working great. I created a keystore to sign the app, created the proper credentials, and have a downloaded `google-services.json` file in my `android\app` folder. 
When I change the package name (which I need to do), the app initializes but throws `GoogleSigninError: DEVELOPER ERROR (code 10)` after I choose an account and authorize scopes. When I check the Google Developer Console, it show requests being made to the clientID associated with the old package name. I've tried:

- reissuing the credentials
- making a new project in the Google Developer Console
- cleaning out the various gradle build directories
- revoking permissions

My instinct from trying to find similar issues is that it's an Android build issue, which I'm not very familiar with. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That means  application is misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and will be treated as fatal. The developer should look at the logs after this to determine more actionable information.

**Generate new android appkeyvand  clientID**  in google console. Because old key config with the old package name .

Comment: Thanks @sasikumar, but that's not the problem. I have already created a brand new project in the Google Console, created credentials in the new project for my new package name, and used the generated `google-services.json` file to replace the old one. The problem is that when I build my project, the values from the old `google-services.json` are used instead of the new values.